# How would I assign multiple MMAP's from single file descriptor?

Tags: c, mmap, x264, file-descriptor, v4l2

So, for my final year project, I'm using Video4Linux2 to pull YUV420 images from a camera, parse them through to x264 (which uses these images natively), and then send the encoded stream via Live555 to an RTP/RTCP compliant video player on a client over a wireless network. All of this I'm trying to do in real-time, so there'll be a control algorithm, but that's not the scope of this question. All of this - except Live555 - is being written in C. Currently, I'm near the end of encoding the video, but want to improve performance.

To say the least, I've hit a snag... I'm trying to avoid User Space Pointers for V4L2 and use mmap(). I'm encoding video, but since it's YUV420, I've been malloc'ing new memory to hold the Y', U and V planes in three different variables for x264 to read upon. I would like to keep these variables as pointers to an mmap'ed piece of memory.

However, the V4L2 device has one single file descriptor for the buffered stream, and I need to split the stream into three mmap'ed variables adhering to the YUV420 standard, like so...

```
buffers[n_buffers].y_plane = mmap(NULL, (2 * width * height) / 3,
                                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                                    fd, buf.m.offset);
buffers[n_buffers].u_plane = mmap(NULL, width * height / 6,
                                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                                    fd, buf.m.offset +
                                    ((2 * width * height) / 3 + 1) /
                                    sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE));
buffers[n_buffers].v_plane = mmap(NULL, width * height / 6,
                                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                                    fd, buf.m.offset +
                                    ((2 * width * height) / 3 + 
                                    width * height / 6 + 1) / 
                                    sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE));
```

Where "width" and "height" is the resolution of the video (eg. 640x480).

From what I understand... MMAP seeks through a file, kind of like this (pseudoish-code):

```
fd = v4l2_open(...);
lseek(fd, buf.m.offset + (2 * width * height) / 3);
read(fd, buffers[n_buffers].u_plane, width * height / 6);
```

My code is located in a Launchpad Repo here (for more background):
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~alex-stevens/+junk/spyPanda/files (Revision 11)

And the YUV420 format can be seen clearly from this Wiki illustration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Yuv420.svg (I essentially want to split up the Y, U, and V bytes into each mmap'ed memory)

Anyone care to explain a way to mmap three variables to memory from the one file descriptor, or why I went wrong? Or even hint at a better idea to parse the YUV420 buffer to x264? :P

Cheers! ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for three separate `mmap`s. Simply `mmap` once, then compute the base pointer for each plane relative to the base pointer of the whole map.

**Edit:** You need something like this:

```
unsigned char *y = mmap(...); /* map total size of all 3 planes */
unsigned char *u = y + y_height*y_bytes_per_line;
unsigned char *v = u + u_height*u_bytes_per_line;
```

Comment: So, how would I have three base pointers, pointing to specific sized partitions within the mmap without memcpy'ing to another piece of memory?

Comment: Sweet, I shall try that now as well. Type casted my mmap with a struct with specific array sizes for Y, U and V (as in the comments of zvrba's post). That seems to work, albeit, hack-ishly lol, your way might be nicer.

Comment: Using a struct for it is not very flexible because it doesn't allow you to support different picture sizes/resolutions. Doing the pointer arithmetic yourself is a lot more flexible.

Comment: Cheers! That worked perfectly too! :P And I definitely see what you mean ^^

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want: you can't make mmap 'uninterleave' sequential memory into separate pointers. You have to mmap a single memory block and manually calculate the appropriate offset within the buffer?

(But: there's absolutely NO REASON for not being able to mmap the same fd several times. You never said what went wrong.)

Comment: Okay, so could you cast the mapped memory to a struct of say: typedef struct { void y_plane[250]; void u_plane[125]; void v_plane[125] } YuvFormat; So you can point to specified ranges of memory from the single mmap?

Comment: Actually... that worked! Now it's just a matter of calculating the lengths of Y, U and V in the YUV420 stream! Cheers :P